# ''Unfortunately, Calendar Storage has stopped'' error on Sony Xperia M (C1905)

Tags: system-error, sony-xperia-m-dual

I get "Unfortunately, Calendar Storage has stopped" because of  which I cannot make calls or send Email from my phone. This affects my work too.

Is there a solution for this issue? I've already formatted my device because it was slow and lagging a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First try rebooting.

Then try deleting app data from the calendar storage app *(pictured below)* preinstalled on your phone

If this problem persists try resetting your phone again.

[image: calendar storage app]